# What's the correct representation of letter "j" in korean?

Tags: hangul

I started learning korean and the book shows c/j as [image], while in other online resources I found it as **ㅈ**

Is this the same, only the first is handwritten version and the second is print version?

I found other letters (for eg. "h") that are also written differently.
Please explain this.

Comment: Yeah, just different fonts. Don't they look similar enough?

Comment: Your second example is just the letter ㅈ in text form, so people will see the shape from the fonts installed in their computer, which is not necessarily the shape you're seeing on *your* computer...

Comment: As others said, it's just a difference in the font. This is really common when first learning and also shows itself when learning different kinds of handwriting. The TTMIK Hangul Master book has a nice section that covers different fonts and handwritings if you want to see morr variations: http://mykoreanstore.com/products/hangeul-master-book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two letters are the same letter - they just look different in different fonts.  Also, in some fonts, like 바탕체 you can see both forms - the first (ㅈ) when it's in the 받침 (bottom of the syllable) and the second when it's in the top of the syllable.

It is usually transliterated as j - that's how the [Revised Romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean) handles it, but the older [McCune–Reischauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCune%E2%80%93Reischauer) transliterates it as 'ch', and I've seen linguistics papers that transliterate it as just 'c'.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same letter in different fonts, as already mentioned.

However, the real answer to your question is **Korean has no representation of the letter "j" or *any* other letter from the English alphabet.**  This kind of thinking will lead you astray and create bad habits.

I remember after about 6 months of studying Korean, when I first got kind of serious about listening to the language and suddenly realizing this fact.  I was blown away..nothing sounded like it "was supposed to"...at all.  There are no sounds that are precisely identical, although some are fairly close.  Remember that.

Answer (score 1):

They are totally the same except the shape. ㅊ and ㅎ are examples of other  letters that can have different shapes. Some people write them with the upper line being vertical, rather than horizontal. Anyway they are totally the same except a little difference in shape.